# Create a popup containing a table

Tags: javascript, json, popup

I'm trying to convert my JSON string into a table on a pop up window. I'm pulling the data from an url and displaying it in an alert right now. The json returns information such as first name, last name, address, etc. and I want to sort the information into a table.  I'll give an example of what I'm using now.

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseSearch">
            <i class="fa fa-search" style="margin-right: 5px;"></i>Search
        </a>
        </h4>   
    </div>
    <div id="collapseSearch" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div id="tocContainer" class="panel-body panel-scroll">
            <form>
                <input placeholder="First Name" id="txtFirstName" type="text" name="fname"><br>
                <br>
                <input placeholder="Last Name" id="txtLastName" type="text" name="lname"><br>
                <br>
                <input type="button" value="Lookup" onclick = "lookUp();">
            </form> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div> 
function lookUp() {
  require(["dojo/request/xhr"

        ], function(
                xhr  
            ) {

        var firstname = document.getElementById('txtFirstName').value;
        var lastname = document.getElementById('txtLastName').value;

        var url = "http:";

        url += firstname + "/" + lastname;

        xhr(url, {
                        handleAs: "json"
                    }).then(function(data){

                        alert(data);
                        }, function(err) {
                           alert('json error - ' + err);
                        }, function(evt) {
                        });


  });
```

Comment: It would be good if you could elaborate a little about exactly what you're trying to achieve here (eg. what do you mean by "clean it up a bit"?)

Comment: Edited the post.  Hope that makes it a little more clear.